# Replace Fragment within ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a little problem with my android app (one Main Activity for the navigation drawer and many fragments).

I havee a list (FragmentList) wich shows me a list of categories. When the user click on a Category he should see the CategoryDetails site. Well,... this is my Error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080042 (com.nma:id/container) for fragment CategoryDetailFragment

I'm trying to replace my CategoriesFragment with the CategoryDetailFragment but it do not work... Can anybody help me?;)

**My mainActivity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.nma.NavigationDrawerFragment"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**my click listener from CategoriesFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new CategoryDetailFragment()).commit();

}
```

**CategoryDetailFragment**

```
public class CategoryDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private View mView;
    private Uri mCategoryUri;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_detail, container, false);

        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**Log**

> 05-19 17:25:25.525  29865-29865/com.nma E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080042 (com.nma:id/container) for fragment
>   CategoryDetailFragment{425649e0 #0 id=0x7f080042}
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
>               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Could you please show us more of the logcat output?

Comment: The code you posted seems fine, you have to show me more. Otherwise I will only be able to guess what the problem might be. What `Activity` are you subclassing? `ActionBarActivity`? `FragmentActivity`? What I mean is are you sure you are using the correct `FragmentManager`? And also as I understand it you have something like this: `Activity -> Fragment1` and want the `Fragment1` to be replaced? I'm asking because if you have something like `Activity -> Fragment1 -> Fragment2` and you wanted to replace `Fragment2` you would have to use the `ChildFragmentManager`.

Comment: My MainActivity extends the android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity. Within this, i start the CategoriesFragment which extends ListFragment (support.v4). When click on a list item, the onListItemClick function are called (see my code above). There i'm trying to replace my ListFragment with the DetailFragment, which extends to Fragment (support.v4). With the ChildFragmentManager i get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `ActionBarActivity` you are supposed to be using the `SupportFragmentManager` instead of the normal one. I am not sure if this is the source of your error but you should try anyways.

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new CategoryDetailFragment()).commit();
```

Of course for this to work you need to use all the classes from the support library instead of the classes that come with the framework. So you need the `FragmentManager` from the support library instead of the normale one and all your `Fragments` need to extend the `Fragment` class from the support library.

Comment: That works fine! Thank you :) PS: i have to call getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager first ;)